# Counterexamples Request- Calculus (limit of series, functions)

Tags: calculus

Can someone help me find counterexamples to the following claims ? at the end of this post I'll state my thoughts

1. If $lim _{n \to \infty} |a_n - b_n |  =1 $ and $a_n$ is convergent (to a final limit) then $b_n $ must also converge.
2. If $a_n $ is convergent and $b_n$ is bounded , then $a_n b_n $ is convergent.
3. If $ lim_{x\to 0 }  f(x^2 ) $  exists and its value is $1$ then $lim_{x\to 0 } f(x)$ is also 1 .
4. If $ lim_{n\to \infty} a_n =0 $ , then $ lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{a_n} =\infty $ .

Thoughts:
2. $a_n $ must also be bounded since it converges... but I can't find suitable series that do not satisfy this condition...

1. My first thought was $\frac{1}{x}$ that has no limit in $0$ ... The problem is that the limit of $f(x^2 )$ in $0$ is infinite, and I want it to be finite...
2. I think that if $a_n$ is positive, then this statement is correct ... But all the non-positive series that I take also satisfy this claim...

Will you please help me ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For $(1)$, consider $a_n=1+\frac 1n,b_n=1+(-1)^n$.  For $(2)$ consider $a_n\cdot\sin(n)$.  For $(3)$, consider $f(x)=e^{-\frac 1x}$, where $\lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x)\ne\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)$.  And for $4$, consider $a_n=\frac {(-1)^n}n$...

Comment: Actually, for $(3)$ use $f(x)=e^{-\frac 1x}+1$...

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot !!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the statements $(1),(2),(3),(4)$ has a counterexample as follows:

1. Let $a_n=1+\frac 1n$ and $b_n=1+(-1)^n$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n-b_n|=1$ but $b_n$ does not converge.
2. Let $a_n$ converge to a non-zero limit $L$ and let $b_n=(-1)^n$.  Then $a_n\cdot b_n$ cannot converge.  Note that since $b_n$ is bounded, if $L=0$ then $a_n\cdot b_n$ will always converge.
3. Let $f(x)=e^{-\frac 1x}+1$ then $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x^2)=1$, but $\lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x)=+\infty$ while $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=1$.
4. Let $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}n$, then $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=0$ while $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac 1{a_n}$ does not exist since alternating terms approach $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ respectively.

Comment: For number 2, if $L=0$ then $a_n \cdot b_n$ converges to $0$.  In fact your example for number 1 would work for 2.

Comment: @Joel: good point.  I'll add that exception

Comment: Thanks a lot again abiessu!

Comment: @homogenity: you're welcome, glad to help.  :-)